# self() property in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that in Javascript, I can call the function self.close() to close my current window.
I was wondering what if rather than closing the window I wanted to alert "foo", is that possible?

which in this case my code would look like

```
   function funky(){
alert("foo");
}
```

can I do this in my html

```
self.funky()
```

To invoke funky? In other words I want to alert my user a message before they close the browser

Comment: Have you tried it? You've written the code here--why not write the same code in a text editor and run it in the browser?

Comment: Yes it'd take 2 seconds to try this out.

Comment: Even if you can, that won't be any different than calling just `funky()`, I guess.

Comment: well, it did not work. Maybe my grammar was wrong.

Comment: Maybe you need this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_event_reference%2Fbeforeunload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global property "self" is just an alias for `window` (in some browsers). Thus any property of `window` can be accessed via "self" too.

If you declare a global function, then it too becomes a property of "self"/`window`.

Answer (score 0):

self and  window  are same object

```
   self === window  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` is not special other than the fact that it is initially set to reference `window`. Similarly, in the global context `this` also refers to `window`. Within functions, `this` will be defined to be the context of the function, and `self` is often used to preserve a context:

```
function Foo() {
    var self;
    self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.bar(); //here `self` references the Foo instance
    }, 1000);
}
Foo.prototype = {
    bar: function () {
        self.console.log('bar!'); //here `self` references `window`
    }
}
new Foo();
```